# How to draw a sankey-like rectangle flow chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a graph like this: Fan Loyalty Changed During the World Cup
[image: Fan Loyalty]

The data I have is a JSON file which includes all the fans support numbers in each round.

Initially, I thought it's very like a Sankey diagram, but I found it's different.
[image: Sankey diagram]

For drawing Sankey, you need to have source node, target node, and value. The source and the target nodes in my case are same, and I don't have the link information. All I have is the number for each layer (can be treated as the node height in Sankey diagram)

And idea of how to draw it using d3.js?

Comment: create `sourceN` and `targetN` nodes and draw a Sankey. N is the layer number.

Comment: A full example: https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/d3-sankey-diagram